# transfer data from one page to another page in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was trying to send my data from one page to another page..
I was using **Session[]** to transfer it,
but the problem is Session is really eat my memory and make my website slower..
Is there any suggestion what will I do?

Comment: Give more details what you're trying to do because this doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: How much data are you storing in session exactly?

Comment: my partner told me to change the session[] part, but I don't know use what function to send the data..
I stored about 12 data around..

Comment: what kind of data are you storing?

Comment: What does your partner suggest?

Comment: some of string data, and some int data..
my partner suggest to use database maybe..

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC? or something else? Give some more data please in order to help you

Comment: Yes I am using ASP.Net MVC..
IDE with VS2013

Comment: what do you guys think if I use Response.Redirect("Page Url"+Variable) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Query String

```
  String s = Request.QueryString["field1"];
```

Comment: will it make my website go faster?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is QueryString, but there are some restrictions of using it:

- the information should be string that must contain characters that are valid for the URL-addresses
- the information would be open for every user and every person who has Internet access
- advanced user can modify querystring and set any other value, that may cause unexpected result
- browsers have length restriction for URL-addresses (1-2 kilobytes)

  If you have no problems with this restrictions you can use QueryString, it's more faster than Session